# How to use \psxlabel and \psylabel to change label size in pstricks plots?

Tags: pstricks, fontsize, labels

I am trying to get larger numbers on my axes in a pstricks plot. The user's guide only says that

```
The labels are set in the current font (ome of the examples above were
preceded by \small so that the labels would be smaller). You can do
fancy things with the labels by redefining the commands:

\psxlabel
\psylabel

E.g., if you want change the font of the horizontal labels, but not the
vertical labels, try something like

\def\psxlabel#1{\small #1}
```

There is, however, no description of the command \pxlabel or example of this line of command's employment. I tried to insert it before and after the \begin{document} line and I had no result.

How can I use this command to change my axes' label font size?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `labelFontSize`, `xlabelFontSize`, `ylabelFontSize`. But you have to use the correct size macro! The labels are set by default in math mode, so `\tiny` for example won't work unless you say `mathLabel=false`!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

Without setting labels in math mode

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(6,6)
\psaxes[mathLabel=false,xlabelFontSize=\tiny,ylabelFontSize=\Large](0,0)(-1,-1)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}

Setting labels in math mode (default)

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(6,6)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle](0,0)(-1,-1)(5,5)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was really helpful.